# Splitting up data in Google Spreadsheet for adjacent columns

Tags: regex, google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula

I would like to split up data from a spreadsheet column (Work ID#, last name, first name) into two adjacent columns.. so that I have 3 separate columns for this data.

Here is a link to my spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gsLYnrNHEMbZTML1YZG-NhtDYO_FAQaAPwGFvtqn2kg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: can you show an example of what your intending the result to be? also there isn't a Work ID column on your spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm working on the basis that column B in your sheet (last_name) contains your merged data, (employee_ID last_name, first_name).

You can do this with three formula, using `regexreplace` and `regexextract`.

**employee_ID**

Put this in cell A1:

`=arrayformula({"employee_ID";iferror(if($B2:$B="","",value(regexextract($B2:$B,"^.*\d"))),"")})`

**first_name**

Put this in cell C1:

`=arrayformula({"first_name";if($B2:$B="","",regexreplace($B2:$B,"^.*\,\ ",""))})`

**last_name**

I created a new column D in front of department. This goes in cell D1:

`=arrayformula({"last_name";if($B2:$B="","",regexreplace(regexreplace($B2:$B,".*\d\ ",""),"\,.*",""))})`

**Summary**

Each one has an array using `{}`. The first part of the array is the column heading in `""`, like `"employee_ID"`. This is so you can keep your formula in row 1 incase you want to add a filter view on the dataset. Then a `;` is a return, then the rest of the cells below: `iferror(if($B2:$B="","",value(regexextract($B2:$B,"^.*\d"))),"")`.

`regexextract($B2:$B,"^.*\d")` looks for anything at the start `^.*`, then a number `\d`.

`value()` converts the result to a number. `iferror` handles where a number can't be found.

On first_name, anything at the beginning `^.*` followed by a comma `\,` then a space `\`  is replaced with `""` (ie. removed).

On last_name, `.*\d\`  replaces anything `.*` followed by a number `\d` followed by a space `\`  with nothing `""` (ie. removed), then from that result another replace removes a comma `\,` followed by anything `.*`.

**Formula in one cell**

If you want to do the split in one go, in say new columns F,G and H, put this in cell F1:

`=arrayformula(iferror(trim(split({"employee_ID,last_name,first_name";if($B2:$B="","",value(regexextract($B2:$B,"^.*\d"))&", "&regexreplace($B2:B,"^.*\d\ ",""))},",")),""))`

However, employee_ID is then formatted as text.

Comment: Happy to help. Let me know if you need anything tweaking :-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the easiest for you is to use the following logic and single formula

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A,"(\d+) (.+), (.+)","$1@$2@$3"),"@")))
```

[image]

*Please write the headings manually. Including them in the formula un-necessarily complicates things. Just make sure that everything below `B2`, `C2` and `D2` is cleared.

Please let us know about info on how the formula works.*

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)
- [`REGEXREPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)

Comment: Really great solution. If you want to avoid a character in your split that could be entered in the source data by mistake `@`, then you could use `char(6655)`. The line would be: `=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE($A2:$A,"(\d+) (.+), (.+)","$1"&char(6655)&"$3"&char(6655)&"$2"),char(6655)),""))`.

Comment: The only downside in putting the formula in row 2 is that you cannot then have a filter view on the source data. If a filter view is needed, then this would work: `=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(SPLIT({"employee_ID"&char(6655)&"first_name"&char(6655)&"last_name";REGEXREPLACE($A2:$A,"(\d+) (.+), (.+)","$1"&char(6655)&"$3"&char(6655)&"$2")},char(6655)),""))`

Comment: @Aresvik You un-necessarily complicate things. Instead of `@` you can use any character not to be found in your data. *(like `♞` or ``)*. As for the filtered views, again, there are simpler ways.