# Split full name into first and last macro automation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking to create a macro which will continually split a given full name in a google sheet cell into First and Last name (two separate columns). The data is continuously being added via a third party integration so I would like this to be continually running on my google sheet as new names are added. Here is the code that I currently have:

```
function FirstLineSplit() {

  var app = SpreadsheetApp;

  var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  var firstRow = activeSheet.getRange(2,1).getValue();

  for(var i=0;i<10;i++) {

    if (firstRow.contains = (" ") {
    activeSheet.getRange(i+2,1).splitTextToColumns(SpreadsheetApp.TextToColumnsDelimiter.SPACE);
     } else if (firstRow.contains != ("")) {

    }
  }
```

Any and all help is appreciated, thank you! Apologies if formatting is incorrect or ugly :p.

Comment: In your situation, in order to run the script, I think that it is required to know the method for adding the data. So, about `The data is continuously being added via a third party integration`, can I ask you about the detail of method for adding the data? By the way, I think that your script is not complete. If you have miscopied your current script, can you modify it?

Comment: It may be easier to use a single array formula (in cell B1) that will do this automatically than to run a script every minute to do it _=Arrayformula (if(A:A<>"";split(A:A;" ";TRUE);))_

Comment: Splitting by space `" "` may cause issues if there are two first names before surname. It would be better to use a regex. This answer covers that scenario: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67408745/splitting-up-data-in-google-spreadsheet-for-adjacent-columns/67409273#67409273

Comment: @Tanaike the new names are being added via a Zap (Zapier) in which the trigger is a closed conversation from a chat service.

Comment: Hi there @WillH773! I have been trying to replicate your issue, but I don't understand where it is. Could you please explain to me where you do need help? Also the two comments on top of mine show valid tools for your scenario, are they useful in your approach?